# Color of the lines are not changing?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, graphics

I want to draw a white line in my window:

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH)); 
        MoveToEx(hdc, 0, 0, 0);
        LineTo(hdc, 100, 100);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    }
```

but the color is still black. What's Wrong?

Comment: By the way, you should be using BeginPaint/EndPaint here, not GetDC/ReleaseDC. EndPaint() clears the update region, and if you don't do that, you'll keep getting WM_PAINT messages over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to set a brush for your line when you should be using a pen. A brush is used to fill the interior of a shape while a pen is used to draw the lines.

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this about pens:

> A pen is a graphics tool that an application can use to draw lines and
>   curves. Drawing applications use pens to draw freehand lines, straight
>   lines, and curves.

And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) about brushes:

> A brush is a graphics tool that applications use to paint the interior
>   of polygons, ellipses, and paths.

Your code would need to be something more like this:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    hdc=BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps); // Used instead of GetDC in WM_PAINT
    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255,255,255));
    HPEN hOldPen = SelectObject(hdc, hPen); 
    MoveToEx(hdc, 0, 0, 0);
    LineTo(hdc, 100, 100);
    SelectObject(hdc, hOldPen);
    DeleteObject(hPen);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps); // Used instead of ReleaseDC in WM_PAINT
}
```

Comment: You can also use `GetStockObject(WHITE_PEN)`.